# UI-route doesn't work with no console errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i was implementing NgRoute, but somewhere in angularjs tutorials they introduce ui-route, i watch some video tutorials about this ui-route, i find it cool and more fluent than the mg-route, so i went to ui-route github page where i've downloaded the js file, i have add it in scripts references, and start following there guide, but i haven't successfully get it to work, and without any console errors, when i go to site web it shows just the index.html !!
App.js

```
var app = angular.module("KhbyraApp", ['ui.router', 'ngCookies']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $urlRouteProvider.otherwise("/login");

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "app/views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: "/register",
        templateUrl: "app/views/register.html",
        controller: "RegisterController"
    })
    .state('articles', {
        url: "/articles",
        templateUrl: "app/views/articles.html",
        controller: "RegisterController"
    });
```

index.html

```
//<html>...
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a ui-sref="articles">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="register">Register</a></li>
            <li ng-if="isAuth" ng-click="LogOut()"><a href="/Logout">LogOut</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
 <div ui-view></div>
 //script....
  </body>
```

Comment: Just a first check... does your `<html>` tag has `ng-app="KhbyraApp"` *(not shown in the snippet)* ...

Comment: yes it does !! i didn't change my index.html it was working with my ng-route, i have changed just config !! and put ui-view directive in my index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a working (simplified) [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzyraCS74NyN55ROa9BK?p=preview), showing that this setting is working.

The only *(but essential)* change is the name of the '$urlRouteProvider' which should be $`urlRouterProvider` *(the router instead of route)*

```
function( $stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
```

Comment: thank you for your plunk, i have fixed it but i don't how i did it, i have replaced ui-route js file to url of source file in there github it worked, so when i replaced the link to my local ui-route file it works !! i didn't understand how it fixed but i think i have delete the cache of the browser!! thank you anyway !!!

Comment: Great the see that. `ui-router` is **awesome** lib